# Copy data from Redshift to ElasticSearch

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-redshift

We have large amount of data stored on ES cluster. I need to add one more field to the ES cluster and upload data for this field from Redshift table’s column. I’ve never work with such data transfer, and I’m new to AWS and not sure how to approach this task and what I should read to perform such data transfer. Do you know what is the best approach to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using logstash doing just the data if yes then you can easily add column in logstash. And restart the lock start from the beginning so that the additional column data is ingested into the index. Let me know what is your current setup.

Answer (score 0):

As i understand you want to dump data from elasticssearch cluster and load it to redshift. 
Here is a approach i would take:

- Dump data from elasticsearch using:https://github.com/taskrabbit/elasticsearch-dump
- Copy the json file to s3 : using aws cli
- Copy the json file from s3 to redshift using : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/copy-usage_notes-copy-from-json.html